# vmalert malformed character constant

Tags: json, yaml, monitoring, victoriametrics

So im trying to make vmalert enforce rules from an api as opposed to a literal yaml file. Once i formatted the rules to json, it said vmalert malformed character constant '%.2f'.
I wrote it after printf. Why can’t vmalert enforce these rules? (the idea behind it is to get 3 digits max per metric)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use double quotes for "%.2f" according to Go docs - see https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals